# MySql REGEXP to match two comma separated strings

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table containing following values :

```
id    |    value      |
-----------------------
1     | 1,2,5,8,12,20 |    
2     | 11,25,26,28   |    
-----------------------
```

now I want to search some comma separated IDs e.g. '1,3,6,7,11' from above value column e.g.

```
SELECT id FROM tbl_name  
WHERE value REGEXP '*some reg exp goes here containing 1,3,6,7,11*'
LIMIT 1,0;

SELECT id FROM tbl_name  
WHERE value REGEXP '*some reg exp goes here containing 3,6,27,15*'
LIMIT 1,0;
```

above 1st query should return 1 while the 2nd should return NULL

I am new with regular expressions can anyone help. Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, it should return `1` because at least one of the numbers matches on the row with that id?

Comment: Just as a side note, don't expect good performance from a query using this data format, it will not be able to use any form of indexes, and will always need to read the whole table to answer the query. In other words, no good for rendering a web page real time if there's more than a few hundred rows of data.

Comment: No that should be the id of that row, and yes it returned if at least one of the number matches.

Comment: You should look into 'one to many' relationships. http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/one-to-many.html

Comment: Are the numbers stored in numeric order, and are the numbers in the search term also in numeric order?

Comment: yes the numbers are sorted ascending.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
REGEXP '(^|,)(1|3|6|7|11)(,|$)'
```

Will match all values containing one number of the sequence `1,3,6,7,11`.

You should not use one column to save several values. Normalize data!

Edited answer

Comment: thanks @Michel, but I want to match if any of the number (at least one) in supplied string matches the value, as in my question 1 matches in the first string and value.

Comment: Updated answer. What do this values stand for? This query will take more time with growing value lengths and table size. I can help you to work out a normalization if you want