# Codeigniter Mysql column with comma seperated values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I wnat to  test a field with multiple values against single value, my SQL is like .

```html
WHERE id (1);
```

Database values are like

```html
id
---
1,2

2,3

1,3,4
```

codeigniter

```html
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('content');
$this->db->where('name', $name);
$this->db->where('id', $id);
```

I tried

```html
$this->db->where_in('id', explode(',', $id));
```

but its not working.Please help me to solve this.

Comment: what is the issue with where_in?

Comment: where_in is working if the id value(eg.(1,2)) and database value(1,2) are same.If id value is 1 and database value is(1,2) its not working.@ Kaleem

Comment: Then like() is not good option for you. It will get records having 2,12,22,32 ...222 and so on when you will search with id=2. [Please look at this option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747223/mysql-regexp-to-match-two-comma-separated-strings). Looks good for your problem

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Kaleem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you use [**`like()`**](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data) instead of  `where()`

```
$this->db->like('id', $id);
// Produces: WHERE `id` LIKE '%2%' ESCAPE '!'
```

> **Note:** If 2 is the value `2`,`22`,`222` will pass through this

Answer (score 6):

To find the values from a given set you can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET(".$id.",id) >", 0);
```

Note: This type of design is considered as a bad design and you should normalize your structure, I suggest you to have a look at [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('table_name')
       ->where("column_name LIKE '%$key_values%'")->get();
```